# Magento 2: Translate input placeholder attribute string in Knockout html template

Tags: magento2, localisation, knockoutjs, inline-translations, js-translation

I can translate strings in Knockout html templates like this:

```
<!-- ko i18n: 'Email' --><!-- /ko -->
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Email'"></span>
```

And the translations come from `pub/static/<area>/<vendor>/<theme>/xx_XX/js-translation.json`.

But I do not know how to translate a value in an HTML attribute, e.g. the placeholder attribute on an input tag, like

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write like this

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr:{placeholder: $t('Email')} " />
```

Run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Worked for me! I didn't need to run any setup commands but the translation is already in my js-translation.json file and I have `layout`, `block_html` and `full_page` cache disabled while developing.

Comment: Yes, but when you changes any content of .html file it require deploy static content. without deploy you can't see your changes.

Comment: You don't need to run a static content deploy unless you're in production mode.

Comment: @BenCrook Have you any document explanation for it?